# Multiple values in one ArrayList key

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to put multiple values in one arraylist key, but instead I get an error:

Class:

```
public class BestellenWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private ArrayList<String> bestelling = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    public BestellenWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }
```

Action performed:

```
private void BestellenbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
    bestelling.add(Barcodetext.getText(), Aantaltext.getText());
    System.out.println(bestelling.get(0));       
}
```

error:

> no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
>       method java.util.ArrayList.add(int,java.lang.String) is not applicable
>         (actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
>       method java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.String) is not applicable

Comment: It appears that what you want to use is `java.util.Map`. Lists do not have keys.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` is just a list. It doesn't have a "key". If you want to store objects by key, use an implementation of interface `Map` (for example `HashMap`) instead of a `List`.

But, a normal `Map` can store only one value per key. If you want to store multiple values, you can use a `Map<K, List<V>>` (where `K` is the key type and `V` the value type), or you could use for example `Multimap` from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

But there's also another, perhaps better solution. Create a new class to hold the barcode and aantal, and store instances of that class in your `ArrayList`. For example:

```
public class Bestelling {
    private String barcode;
    private int aantal;

    public Bestelling(String barcode, int aantal) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.aantal = aantal;
    }

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public int getAantal() {
        return aantal;
    }
}

// Later:
Bestelling b = new Bestelling(Barcodetext.getText(),
                              Integer.parseInt(Aantaltext.getText()));
bestelling.add(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java there are two elements. 
1. List Interface : This does not hold any key. It has the collection of the values. You can add one by one by add(value) method.
2. Map : This holds one key for a set of value.

```
List<String> userName = new ArrayList<String>();
userName.add("Jesper");
userName.add("Mafue");

Map<Long,String> userMap = new HashMap<Long,String>();
userMap.put(1l,"Jesper");
userMap.put(2l,"Mafue");
```

From map you can retrieve the values by providing key.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke the method

```
list.add(int index, String value)
```

that it is used to insert an element at a specific position.

If this is what you actually want to do then I guess that `Barcodetext` should contain a string that is a number, so you need to convert it to an `int` with

```
Integer.parseInt(Barcodetext.getText())
```

If instead you want to add multiple values just call the method twice:

```
bestelling.add(Barcodetext.getText());
bestelling.add(Aantaltext.getText());
```

Comment: Do I need to define the parsed integer, to put it into the arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

```
bestelling.add(...);
bestelling.add(...);
...
```

or

```
bestelling.addAll(Arrays.asList(..., ...));
```